# How to use an XM+ receiver without a flight controller?

Tags: frsky, sbus, receiver

All of the model aircraft I have seen without flight controllers normally have a receiver with all of the channels separate. Is there any way I can use a receiver like an XM+ receiver on a model aircraft without a flight controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you most certainly can. The device you will need is called an SBus Decoder, which splits the SBus serial signal from your FrSky XM+ into several different PWM channels.

- [Example of an 8-channel SBus decoder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00X767R2I)
- [Example of a 16-channel SBus decoder](https://www.banggood.com/16CH-SBUS-to-PWMPPM-Decoder-Compatible-for-Futaba-Frsky-Transmitter-p-1250019.html)

[image: Example of an 8-channel SBus decoder]